# Kafka scala Code is running in eclipse but not using jar file

Tags: scala, maven, apache-kafka

Code is running in eclipse but not using jar file. Please finf below details

ERROR -

```
D:\ecl_WeatherData\performance\target>scala -cp D:\ecl_WeatherData\performance\target\weatherData-0.0.1.jar dataPipeline.produceWeatherData
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at dataPipeline.weatherDataProducer.writeToKafka(weatherDataProducer.scala:44)
    at dataPipeline.produceWeatherData$.delayedEndpoint$dataPipeline$produceWeatherData$1(produceWeatherData.scala:15)
    at dataPipeline.produceWeatherData$delayedInit$body.apply(produceWeatherData.scala:3)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at dataPipeline.produceWeatherData$.main(produceWeatherData.scala:3)
    at dataPipeline.produceWeatherData.main(produceWeatherData.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:70)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:70)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:65)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Below is POM file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.pm.sparkjobs</groupId>
<artifactId>weatherData</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10 -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency> 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
<artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
<version>2.11.11</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
<version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
<version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

And Scala version is 2.11.11

Comment: You don't need `kafka_2.11` or `spark-streaming_2.11` to use Spark to consume from Kafka. And if you want structured streaming, then not `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10` either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you have to add the dependency of kafka client on the jar:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

And, in case you are not doing yet, use the assembly plugin to create a fat jar with dependencies:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

And compile using `mvn clean compile assembly:single`.

Comment: Added assembly plugin and able to run the jar